# Python PEP: blank line after function definition?

Tags: python, coding-style, styles, pep

I can't find any PEP reference to this detail. There has to be a blank line after function definition?

Should I do this:

```
def hello_function():
    return 'hello'
```

or shoud I do this:

```
def hello_function():

    return 'hello'
```

The same question applies when docstrings are used:

this:

```
def hello_function():
    """
    Important function
    """
    return 'hello'
```

or this

```
def hello_function():
    """
    Important function
    """

    return 'hello'
```

**EDIT**

This is what the PEP says on the blank lines, as commented by FoxMaSk, but it does not say anything on this detail.

> Blank Lines
>
> Separate top-level function and class definitions with two blank
>   lines.
>
> Method definitions inside a class are separated by a single blank
>   line.
>
> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of
>   related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of
>   related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).
>
> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
>
> Python accepts the control-L (i.e. ^L) form feed character as
>   whitespace; Many tools treat these characters as page separators, so
>   you may use them to separate pages of related sections of your file.
>   Note, some editors and web-based code viewers may not recognize
>   control-L as a form feed and will show another glyph in its place.

Comment: I read it as "don't you do no friggin' space-wasting empty lines not, unless one of these rare exceptions apply".

Come on – does it really increase readability to separate the `def` from the code?

Comment: I definitely read that as being an exhaustive list of all the places you can put vertical whitespace. Saying that, I would put a single blank line between imports based on where they come from. Grouping core python libs, 3rd party libs, and homegrown libs together. In that order.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Read [Docstring Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

It says that even if the function is really obvious you have to write a one-line docstring. And it says that:

> There's no blank line either before or after the docstring.

So I would code something like

```
def hello_function():
    """Return 'hello' string."""
    return 'hello'
```

Comment: I can't find anything in the doc that says you *must* write a docstring, even for really obvious functions.  I'm a big fan of docstrings, but if the docstring cannot add anything to the readability, I would omit it altogether.

I've seen this before:
```
def set_main_window_icon(self, icon_path):
        """Set main window icon."""
```
and that is a waste of lines.  I get that hello_function is a contrived invention, but I worry about encouraging that sort of docstring by example.

Comment: But I'd absolutely recommend placing blank line after docstring if your function already 
has empty lines somewhere.

Comment: Nowhere in the conventions it says that "even if the function is really obvious you have to write a one-line docstring". What it does say is _"[...] all functions and classes exported by a module should also have docstrings. Public methods (including the __init__ constructor) should also have docstrings"_, which means that public interfaces (exported functions, public methods) should have a docstring. It says nothing about private methods and internal functions.

Answer (score 35):

As pointed out by @moliware, the [Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) state, under [One-line Docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id16):

> There's no blank line either before or after the docstring.

HOWEVER, it also says (under [Multi-line Docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id17)):

> Insert a blank line after **all** docstrings (one-line or multi-line) that *document a **class*** -- generally speaking, the *class's methods are separated from each other by a single blank line*, and the docstring needs to be offset from the first method by a blank line.

My interpretation of all this: blank lines should never precede any docstring, and should only follow a docstring when it is for a class.

Answer (score 1):

Projects use different docstring conventions.

For example, the `pandas` [docstring guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing_docstring.html#general-rules) explicitly requires you to put triple quotes into a line of their own.

> Docstrings must be defined with three double-quotes. No blank lines should be left before or after the docstring. **The text starts in the next line after the opening quotes**. The closing quotes have their own line (meaning that they are not at the end of the last sentence).

Answer (score 0):

Making a python script simultaneously adhere to `pydocstyle` and `pycodestyle` is a challenge. But one thing which greatly helps is that in your docstring write the first line as summary of the function or class within 79 characters including `.`.This way you adhere to both PEP 257 (as per `pydocstyle`) of having a period at the end of an unbroken line and 79 characters limit of PEP 8 (as per `pycodestyle`).

Then after leaving one blank line (for that using new line shortcut of your coditor is better than manually pressing `enter`) you can write whatever you want and at that time focusing only on `pycodestyle` which is slightly easier than `pydocstyle` and the main reason is that our understanding of line and indentation is quite different than what system understands due to indentation settings, tab settings, line settings in the various code editors we use.So in this way you will have `TODO` from `pycodestyle` which you understand and can rectify instead of banging your head against the wall on `pydocstyle` `TODO`s.